# I set my transaction fee too low 2 months ago and blockchain says "transaction invalid", will I get my coins back?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, mycelium-wallet

About 2 months ago I sent BTC from my Mycelium wallet to an XMR exchange, however I set the transaction fee too low so it never got any confirmations. I found the transaction on blockchain.info and it would start off saying unconfirmed, then after some time it would say "Transaction invalid: some outputs that it attempts to spend have been already spent or are no longer valid" (although I have done nothing else with the bitcoin), then sometimes when I checked the transaction on Mycelium every few days it would rebroadcast and the same cycle would happen.

After 3-4 weeks I let the transaction rebroadcast once more and then deleted the transaction from Mycelium, so it would not rebroadcast anymore - I was hoping that after couple weeks the transaction would drop from the mempool and I would be refunded the coins. However this was now over 4 weeks ago and there is still no sign of the coins coming back. What should I do? Should I just wait it out and they will be guaranteed to come back eventually, or is there some action I should take?

Here is the transaction on blockchain: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/4367ed782f5347ec5184b597d38267ccd117c0705b419bda5911d3a199df3483

Comment: If the transaction never gets confirmed, the money never left your wallet and, so far as the Bitcoin network is concerned, is still under your control, even if your wallet doesn't show it. Since it never left, the notion of it coming back is not necessary. Bitcoin has no notion of refunds.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, it is good to know my coins are still technically safe. I read through that thread and I'm still unsure because the blockchain says my transaction is invalid, so I suppose that means there is no chance of it getting confirmed. But my wallet is still showing its funds to be empty (although I understand they were never sent), should I expect that they will show up again at some point?

Comment: Probably not - you should find a way to convince Mycelium that the transaction doesn't exist. If that happens, it should show you the original balance again. I have no idea how to do this, but I don't expect this is something time based. There isn't any event that needs to happen; you just need to convince your wallet the coins never left.

Comment: Thank you Pieter, I will see what I can do on the app to fix this.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, I have managed to solve the issue, I simply deleted the Mycelium app and reinstalled it, having made sure my wallet was backed up. I suppose it must've been some glitch that prevented the funds from showing.

Answer (score -1):

Contact the person you sent it to sometimes they can speed up a transaction. Like when i sent a small amount of btc to localbitcoins in 2017, the can see the transaction and somehow point their miners specifically at that transaction. Maybe i don't recall correctly.but it took like two weeks and that was a long time then. Sounds like it's getting far worse. Probably will continue to get worse and worse. Bitcoin could be completely obsolete in another 3 to 6 years because it will be so slow.

I think the only thing you can do is wait. There's no centralized regulations that you can complain to. Very to hear that. Next time increase the transaction fee. The fees are godawful and are ruining crypto.